# How to check if a byte[] holds any bytes client side using Eval?

Tags: asp.net, arrays, eval

I have a gridview and one of the cells will show a link to a file, if the file is present in the database, however my Eval is not working.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Certificate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("imgCertificate") == null ? "" : "View" %>' ID="hlFile" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

When I run the code, I always get the link because the imgCertificate object is not null it is a byte[0].  How can I check against this?

EDIT:  Here is my new code and now I am getting the following error:

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Certificate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%#(byte[])Eval("imgCertificate").Length == 0 ? "" : "View" %>' ID="hlFile" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: That error is caused by missing parentheses.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether `((byte[])Eval("imgCertificate")).Length == 0`

Comment: This is throwing me an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: when I check to see if it is null it is not, but when I check if the length == 0 I get null??? I am confused...  I put my updated code up top if you all could help me that would be great, I could always do it on databind but I would really like to figure out what is wrong with it now...